GUI dependency and sql_expression not matching up
I'm using pubs database on SQL Server 2016 standard. I'm trying to track the dependency for the titles table using UI dependency tracker vs sql_expression_dependency and I'm getting different results. Can you help me understand why the difference?
Microsoft article reference [Go]
USE pubs
GO  
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,   
    o.type_desc AS referencing_description,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id,   
    referencing_class_desc,  
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,  
    referenced_entity_name,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,  
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous  
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id  
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.titles');  


SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( referencing_id ) AS referencing_schema_name,  
    OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,   
    o.type_desc AS referencing_description,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id,   
    referencing_class_desc, referenced_class_desc,  
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,  
    referenced_entity_name,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,  
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous  
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id  
WHERE referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.titles');  
GO



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Start by using SQL Profiler to capture the query that the SSMS GUI uses to fetch that data.

@ThomA Honestly, in this case, a screenshot is better than markdown tables.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft SQL Profiler won't show any of the SMO voodoo that SSMS uses internally (e.g. procedure/function parameter extraction).

It's not for the text the OP highlights at the bottom though, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft .

@dai SMO doesn't have a private API to SQL Server.  It runs TSQL queries just like any other client library.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I’m not alleging that. I’m saying that (at least a few) of the “things”/objects/nodes in SSMS that are shown in the Object Explorer are not directly exposed in DMVs/sys.-views/etc, instead SSMS reads things like the routine/script source (from the public and documented APIs) and uses its own parser to extract/derive structure/metadata/etc. I understand some of the Dependency tracing functionality in SSMS does this which means it’s basically impossible to do it oneself - at least not without taking a dependency on SMO. Another example is “Script object…” too.

@Dai that's a very good point. Stored procedure parameter defaults is one of those things, they cannot be gleaned from a view and must be parsed from the source code

@siggemannen It accomplishes that with some very gnarly Regex patterns in SMO. Infer from that what-you-will :)

@Dai i suspect the reason SMO isn't open sourced yet is out of shame not secret keeping :)
